# Is there a functional way to get a count of how many arrays intersect with at least one other array?

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose the following array of arrays:

```
[
    [
        'value_1',
        'value_2',
        'value_3',
    ], [
        'value_1',
        'value_4',
        'value_5'
    ], [
        'value_6',
        'value_7',
        'value_8'
    ]
]
```

I want to calculate how many arrays intersect with *at least* one other array. So in the above case, I want to ultimately get the result `2`, because the first and second arrays intersect with one another. The above is a very simple array; the array I'm working with is much, much larger.

I could easily do this with a couple nested loops and a temporary holding array which I then `count`, but I'm hoping there might be a more elegant, functional way to do this.

I've gone down the list of PHP array functions and played around with different iterations of `array_intersect`, but I feel that's not the correct solution to my problem - `array_intersect` looks for common intersections across *all* arrays, not *any* arrays.

So: is there a PHP method, or flag for an existing method, or interaction between multiple methods, that I'm not aware of? Or is my only option the distinctly uglier series of loops?

Comment: Only one item in the array needs to intersect? Does position in the array matter?

Comment: Correct - only one item need intersect with one item in any other array. Position doesn't matter, only value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple solution without loops and functional programming, but you could build something

```
$array = [
    [
        'value_1',
        'value_2',
        'value_3',
    ], [
        'value_1',
        'value_4',
        'value_5'
    ], [
        'value_6',
        'value_7',
        'value_8'
    ]
];

$sum = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function($item) use (&$sum){
    $sum[$item] = isset($sum[$item]) ?  $sum[$item] + 1 : 1;
});
$filter = array_filter($sum, function($item) {
    return $item > 1;
});

$result = array_filter($array, function($a) use ($filter) {
    return count(array_intersect_key(array_flip($a), $filter)) == 0;
});

print_r($result);
```

The main idea behind this solution is to create a blacklist of items, which shouldn't occur in the inside array. In your case, `value_1` occours two times and so is a blacklist item.

This blacklist is later used with an intersection. If the intersection is empty, the inner item is "unique", else not.

In case of large arrays with a small "blacklist", this could be even faster than a simple nested loop, as the main complexity is linear in O(n).

Comment: I find this to be the most informative and well-written answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_unique()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

And count the diffrence between the values of both arrays using array_count_values()

Comment: I don't think this would work. That is for a single associative array. We are talking about an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily loop through all arrays...

```
$intersections = 0;
foreach($arrays in $k=>$arr){
    //Dont start at 0 here, it would repeat some checks.
    for($i=$k+1;$i<count($arrays);$i++){
        if(count(array_intersect($arr,$arrays[$i]))>0){
            $intersections++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit for more info:

We use array_intersect as you hinted to see if 2 arrays have similar values, count the amount of values returned to see if they share any. If they do we add the count, and get out of the loop since we want to count how many arrays, and not how many times.

Comment: I know, I did say in the question that I knew I could easily loop through - as I said, I'm hoping there might be a more functional (see: less ugly) way of doing it.

Comment: Then no... Wrapping it in a function should be all you want/need. It is not ugly, cannot get more "functional" either.